# Ajax Toolkit - Modal popal position resetting after internal update panel refreshes

Tags: c#, updatepanel, modalpopupextender

I have a modal popup that can be dragged and moved. It also contains an ajaxUpdatePanel to update certain elements within it.

My problem is that if the modal popup has been moved around and the update panel fires, the popup will pop back to center position. Nothing breaks, it's just annoying to end users.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You may use script below:

```
var x = null;
var y = null;

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
     var extender = $find("ModalPopupExtender1"); // extender's  BehaviorID
     if (extender != null && x != null && y != null) {
          extender.set_X(parseInt(x));
          extender.set_Y(parseInt(y));
     }
}

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
     var extender = $find("ModalPopupExtender1");  // extender's BehaviorID
     x = extender._foregroundElement.style.left;
     y = extender._foregroundElement.style.top;
}
```

If you'll close popup and open it again without full postback it will save previous position, but the next time it will be centered again.